# Find the Fourier Sine series of $x-\frac{1}{2}$ on the interval $0<x<1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Two Parts to this question are:

(a) Find the Fourier Sine series of $x-\frac{1}{2}$ on the interval $0<x<1$

(b) Let $a \notin Z$ and find the Fourier Cosine Series of $\cos ax$ on the interval $0<x<\pi$

---

I am working on part (a) and this is what I have so far:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\sin(nx)dx= \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{-\cos(nx)}{n}\right)+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}dx=$$

This is where I get stuck. Can someone please help me continue from there ?

Comment: Yes, look for the Fourier coefficients (extending the function periodically such that it is an odd function)

Comment: @VladimirVargas Would you be able to hep me continue? I've added to the work

Comment: Should probably be $\sin(2\pi n x)$ instead of $\sin(nx)$ for part (a).